# Java method to count the characters of a string

Tags: java, string, netbeans, count, character

I have a string named text and I want to count the number of its characters.
But there is no method 'count' like in ObjC.

In the Internet I found the method 'length', which could be useful. But If I write:

```
private javax.swing.JTextField txtText;
    int counter = txtText.length();
```

the compiler complains: "cannot find the symbol"

I thought I need a framework to include, I am absolutely new in Java.

Comment: This should work.  Can you show us the declaration of `text`?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? This is probably a scope problem.

Comment: Please show the *actual error message* as your question is missing a *lot* of important details. Also, show the code above and below this line and let us know where this line of code is located. Is it in a method or constructor? I'll bet that you have this line hanging out naked in the class and not enclosed in a method, constructor, or other similar block. Or else as others have stated, your text variable is out of scope, but right now until you supply the details needed you're making us guess which isn't playing nice.

Comment: Show us the rest of your code, so that we at least know what the type of text is. And don't google for information about class methods, but read their javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: You don't have any code that gets the text from your text field. If you are, then it is probably a scope problem. If you aren't then that is probably the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must get the text from your GUI-component first:

```
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField;

String text = jTextField.getText();
int counter = text.length();
```

JTextField itself is a GUI-Component and not a String. But `getText()` method gives you the text entered in this component as a String which you can then use to determine the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
String hello = "Hello World!";
int length = hello.length();
```

Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work, have you checked that everything was spelled correctly?

```
String text="THIS IS A TEST";
int counter = text.length();
```

If that still doesn't work make sure your IDE and your project are setup correctly.